# Asp.Net Core Runtime

Tags: asp.net-core

Как узнать ОС в которой выполняется приложение (Win или Linux)? И можно ли определить, что оно запущено в docker-контейнере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform
```

Возвращает enum `System.PlatformID`

```
Win32S
Win32Windows
Win32NT
WinCE
Unix
Xbox
MacOSX
```

---

Проверка на запущенность в Docker, [работает при использовании стандартных образов](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/2.1/runtime-deps/alpine3.7/amd64/Dockerfile):

```
private bool InDocker
{
    get
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER") == "true";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1 способ**

Метод:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform()
```

Аргументы:

```
OSPlatform.Windows
OSPlatform.OSX
OSPlatform.Linux
```

Пример:

```
bool isWindows = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation
                                               .IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)
```

**2 способ**

```
var osNameAndVersion = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.OSDescription
```